# crontab (cronie), run certain days of the month

Tags: linux, cron, fedora, dayofmonth

I want to make a crontab entry which will run on every weekday except the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd of each month.  Here's what I have:

```
45   8,12,16 4-31 * 1-5  my_program
```

I thought that this had the following meaning:

```
minutes:      45 past the hour
hours:        8, 12, and 16
day of month: 4th to 31st inclusive
month:        all
day of week:  Monday to Friday inclusive
```

That is what I read in the `crontab(5)` manual page.  However, I can see that the job ran at 08:45 today, Monday 2nd October.  I am certain the crontab file was loaded correctly (and `crontab -l` shows it); it wasn't changed recently.  The system date and time as shown by `date` is also correct.

What am I missing to make sure my cron job only runs from the 4th onwards?  I am using Fedora Linux:

```
% rpm -qf `which crontab`
cronie-1.5.0-3.fc23.x86_64
% rpm -q fedora-release
fedora-release-23-1.noarch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `crontab` manual:

> Note:  The  day  of  a  command's execution can be specified by two
>   fields — day of month, and day of week.  If both fields are restricted
>   (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either field
>          matches the current time.  For example,
>          ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday. One can, however,
>   achieve the desired result by adding a test to the  command  (see
>          the last example in EXAMPLE CRON FILE below).

The mentioned example looks like this:

```
0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
```

So in your case it would be like this (not tested):

```
45   8,12,16 4-31 * *  test $(date +\%u) -lt 6 && my_program
```

Comment: Thanks -- what a strange little wrinkle in the crontab semantics!  In the end I will just run it on all days of the week, since I don't care much about that but I do want to avoid start of month.